# C# - Stackoverflow exception when adding to HashSet<T>

Tags: c#, exception, overflow, hashset

I have got a class called Team.

```
class Team
{
        public Team(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Wins = 0;
            this.Opponents = new HashSet<Team>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Wins { get; set; }
        public HashSet<Team> Opponents { get; set; }
}
```

I get a Stackoverflow exception whenever i try to add an existing team with a single opponent in another team's HashSet that has zero Opponents `guestTeam.Opponents.Add(homeTeam);`

Here hometeam has a single opponents in Opponents while `guestTeam.Opponents` is still empty.

Its a small test app. ***Stacktrace's framecount shows 3.***

Any ideas why would i get such an exception thrown?

Comment: Show the code that causes the exception. Btw, if you use a custom class in a `HashSet` you should override `Equals`+`GetHashCode`meaningfully and/or implement `IEquatable<Team>`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter not really required to override `Equals+GetHashCode` if you are ok with comparing references.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: true, but since the `HashSet<>` is even a public property in this class he should know that he could still add duplicate teams(f.e. same name) if he uses different instances. That is usually undesirable. In this case it's certainly a code smell

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is true, he should be aware of that, but the code seems simple enough that my guess is he does not use multiple instances. But you make a good point :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: what code? It's a public property, even other assemblies could use it and add different instances with same names

Comment: Guys its just a test. I'm aware that the property is public. Had the problem elsewhere and i wrote this quickly. However I missed overriding the Equals, which is the solution to my problem. Thanks a lot Tim, cheers :)

Comment: Nope, still the same mistake. The line that breaks the program is guestTeam.Opponents.Add(homeTeam);

Comment: Can you show a code? Because I can't reproduce that error.

Answer (score -1):

I admit, I can't reproduce error. personally I could go into properly implement of

```
: IEquatable<Team>
```

And then:

```
        public bool Equals(Team other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return string.Equals(this.Name, other.Name) && Equals(this.Opponents, other.Opponents);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Team)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((this.Name != null ? this.Name.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ (this.Opponents != null ? this.Opponents.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Team left, Team right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Team left, Team right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
```

Of course I am cannot reproduce that so it's just shot.